# Fixed image mask reveal image underneath on scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed, mask

there is probably a super simple solution to this...

I'm trying to create a portfolio page and I want to show a screenshot of a mobile site in context.

So for example, I have a tall screenshot image of the full page and I want to have it masked by an image of a mobile phone where it will only show up on the screen area. As you scroll, I want the phone to have fixed positioning and reveal the screenshot underneath in its "viewport".

Here's a diagram of what I mean:

[image]

Any thoughts?